# Should I use rel="nofollow" on already existing internal links?

Tags: seo, nofollow

I have a big video website. It's not in the index yet, I try to do my best for better indexing before opening and now I have a question. New videos are displayed on the main page and there's a navigation for accessing pages with an older videos. On the page with any video there's a section with related videos (without navigation). There are no videos displayed that the robot couldn't access through the main page. Furthermore, these videos a little bit changes with every page refresh. Should I add an `rel="nofollow"` attribute to links in this section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, never `nofollow` internal links.

Matt Cutts, Google Search engineer, said that [he doesn't use nofollow on his website's category or archive pages](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/pagerank-sculpting/), which are similarly dynamically generated like your related videos section is.

If one of the guys who ran Google Search didn't bother with it on his website, neither should you.